# Shell Cron Error - What could cause this error?

Tags: php, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

**Description:** I am not very familiar with using a lot of bash/shell. I currently have a cron tab set up on an Ubuntu server that runs a Shell script. The Shell script then is suppose to run a PHP script, however, instead I am getting the following error message:

**Could not open input file: wscript.php**

At the top of my shell script I have written #!/bin/bash

Then the shell script itself I am passing a bash variable to PHP script.

```
 while read bashvariable
 do
   php wscript.php "$bashvariable"
 done
```

Keep in mind when I run this this shell script manually the script executes and fires correctly.

At the top of wscript.php I have placed in #!/usr/local/bin/php.

wscript.php has an include file of wscript-add.php

I have attempted to change the permission of all files to 777 and I haven't had any luck on getting the cron tab to run correctly.

Below is what my cron tab looks like:

```
*/2 * * * * sh /var/www/website/wcron/wcron.sh
```

**My Question:** What could cause my PHP file to not fire correctly when used by cron? Do I need specific file permissions on each file to run correctly?

Comment: `chmod 777` is always the wrong solution.  Now you have two problems.

Comment: I changed my chmod after having the issue resolved. I only did so to test the permission settings to see if that was an issue in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify full path to php script as when cron runs, it uses different current directory.

Comment: @Ryan you are welcome :) It's a very common caveat that I think everyone had been trapped into.